# SSL certificate issue on Firefox, Ubuntu on a Windows network behind a proxy

Tags: windows, ubuntu, proxy, ssl, certificate

My Problem:
SSL enabled sites (HTTPS) do not render properly on my Firefox browser. The network team at office says that the issue is because the proxy server isn't able to identify my system correctly, and hence the exchange of certificates on the proxy server isn't working as it should. HTTPS sites like banking sites render properly. It seems these sites are bypassed by the proxy to prevent decryprting-encrypting the requests. The network team has given me a certificate (.p12) file to import into Firefox, but that does not help.

This issue only occurs on Linux systems. I have put down the correct domain name in the smb.conf file, to have my system on the domain, but that isn't helping me too.

Setup:
I am on a Ubuntu 11.10 machine and use Firefox 14 browser. I am on a Windows Network in office, behind a Proxy server.

Any information or lead will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a MITM proxy? When you look at the certificate details of an external website from within your network, do you get the same details as you would see from a network where you know you're connecting directly (e.g. home or mobile network)?

Comment: I am behind a proxy but I don't know if I am behind a MITM proxy specifically. Will find out and update you. But it seems there is a certificate exchange that happens at the proxy server, and I do not get the same certificate as I would get if I am not behind the proxy server (i.e. if I am accessing Internet from home).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you get a different certificate behind this proxy within this network and without this proxy seems to indicate that this is an SSL-inspecting proxy (or "MITM proxy").

A proxy server like this is able to look into the encrypted SSL/TLS traffic by impersonating the target server. They do this by generating their own certificate, replacing that of the genuine server. Such a certificate is issued by a CA embedded within the proxy server (which may be able to generate the certificate dynamically). Such certificates are recognised by the workstations within the company network (or similar, wherever that proxy server is installed), because these machines have been configured to trust the CA certificate of the proxy server in addition (or instead of) the default CA certificate list provided with the OS or browsers.

(You could see this as a "legitimate MITM attack", which isn't actually an attack, since the trust in that extra CA certificate must have been approved by the local policy makers and set up by the system administrators.)

It's very likely that the installation on that CA certificate was done by your sysadmin team on the Windows machines, but your Ubuntu machine might have been left out (very likely if you've installed it yourself). It's not about the proxy server not being able to identify your system correctly; rather it's your system that's not configured to trust your proxy server.

You'd need to install that CA certificate yourself on your machine and in your browser. You could ask your network team for that CA certificate, or you should be able to export it yourself from a Windows box: look at the issuer cert for any of the website you visit from a machine where the connection works (usually accessible with something like "view details", depending on the browser you're using there), export it (PEM/Base-64) and import it on your Linux machine.

You'll need to import it into Firefox as a trusted authority (Options/Preferences -> Advanced -> Encryption -> View Certificates -> Authorities -> Import... and tick "trust this CA certificate" for identifying web sites). Other applications have different CA certificate repositories: it may be useful to make a copy into `/etc/ssl/certs/` too.

Of course, the result is that whoever is in charge of that proxy server will be able to look at the traffic you're exchanging on any HTTPS site you're using from that network, but that's already the case from any Windows machine configured this way anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I will try it for a few days and if all goes fine, I'll then mark it as the answer. Cheers! :)